# AngularJS ng-repeat and attrs

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML:

```
<load ng-repeat="item in widget" type="item.type"></load>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('load', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {

            console.log(attrs.type);
            return 'templates/camera.html';
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',


    };
});
```

attrs.type return string item.type, how can I get value of item.type? Ofc in array is type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited :

your templateUrl is a function ? ???

correct directive is this :

```
    app.directive('load',function(){
      return{
       restrict:'E',
       templateUrl:'yourTemplate.html'
       link:function(scope,elem,att){
        console.log(att.type)
         scope.$apply(function(){
             scope.types.item = att.item;// you can overrite like this , or use push() to scope.types
             // this way you have access to your item in your templateUrl ;
             // Remeber , there should be a $scope.types={} in your controller!!!!
             // after this , in your templateUrl if you write {{types.item}}
             // you can get your data 
          })

         }

 }

});
```

Add curly braces {{item.type}}

```
       <load ng-repeat="item in widget" type="{{item.type}}"></load>
```

Comment: Sorry, but return also string: {{item.type}}

Comment: The OP used template, not link. Template doesn't get the scope.

Comment: Ty, but how can I use this att.type in my template url? example: templateUrl:'your'+att.type+'.html'

Comment: When I used Your code have error: http://pastebin.com/7anWWfpb and when want use {{types.item}} have undefined

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a variable named "type" in scope, you would need to use `link` instead of `template`. Then you can use the following:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var variableName = attrs.type.split(".")[0];
    var attribute = attrs.type.split(".")[1];
    console.log(scope[variableName][attribute]);
};
```

That should do it. Best of luck!

**See The Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/M2p27P5yGZC273AcTxOM?p=preview

**Other Notes**

- You should really check to see if the item exists before you try to access it. If it doesn't you will probably get something like `cannot access type of undefined` or something along those lines.
- This will only work with an object name and type. If you want to get more complicated than this you should consider a regular expression to parse the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your link function, try:

```
var type = scope.$eval(attrs.type);
```